# how difficult is learning windows mobile development for winforms developer

Tags: winforms, windows-phone

Forgive me as this is not programming related question.

I know ASP.NET as well as WinForms development. I would like to know that if i want to learn windows mobile development how difficult it would be for me to start.

- Is there a big difference between the two platforms ?
- Is coding style and creating form design too different ?

Comment: don't worry about the difficulty because if you know some coding and zeal to learn everything is fine..so follow these links.. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know WinForms then you can most certainly rest assured that the Windows Phone platform will be a breeze to learn. I too came from a WinForms background and I found it pretty much a walk in the park to get in terms with Windows Phone. There are of course subtle differences in WinForms and Windows Phone such as Windows Phone uses Silverlight, which is a toned down version of WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) which is in turn a powerful version if you like of WinForms.

But again, these are subtle differences and you will easily become comfortable using the Windows Phone API.

There are many tutorials on how to get started. Just google or youtube Windows Phone tutorial and you'll find many.

In terms of **Coding Style**, there are no real differences. The Windows Phone platform is obviously C# compatible so you can quite literally adhere to the same design patterns as you would with a WinForms application.

The main difference I suppose is the use of XAML. When designing a page, you can drag and drop controls which creates XAML.

Comment: Thanks. XAML is not that much new to me as i know a little of WPF.